# Error 1215 cannot add foreign key

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE Instructors(
    ID  CHAR(5), 
    name    VARCHAR(30), 
    deptName     VARCHAR(20),
    salary           FLOAT(12,2),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (deptName) REFERENCES Instructors(deptName));
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with this statement... help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We can't tell what's wrong with this unless you show us what your whole table structure looks like. Most likely, the Instructors table does not have a `deptName` field (just a guess).

Comment: See all the **Related** questions in the sidebar? I'll bet at least one of them has the same problem as you. Make sure the datatypes are the same, including the same collation.

Comment: You appear to be trying to create a foreign key constraint that references itself.

Comment: I think in the `REFERENCES` you need to write the other table name whom you need to refer. You are writing the same table name which you are creating. Correct that your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key needs to reference the other table, and the name of the column in that table, probably something like:

```
FOREIGN KEY (deptName) REFERENCES Departments(name));
```